# Android Eclipse. Test class not found in select project

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, eclipse-adt, android-espresso

I create test project. My steps:

1. File - New -Project;
2. Choose - Android Test Project;
3. Set name's project;
4. Choose project when I want test;
5. Choose SDK target version;
6. Click Finish.

Done, I create libs folder and add to it espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundled.jar. Project's structure looks
[image]

Done, I create test class:

```
public class TestT extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>
```

{

```
public TestT(Class<MainActivity> activityClass)
{
    super(activityClass);
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
{}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception
{}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{}

@Test
public void test()
{
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@SmallTest
public void testTest()
{
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnClick)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.tvClick)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText(MainActivity.TEXT)));
}
```

}

Done, I run test project:

1. Right click on test project;
2. Run as - Android JUnit project;

Project is run, but it isn't any displaying.
I open Window - Show View - Java - JUnit:
[image]

Double click on emulator-5554 show me dialog:
[image]

I try in all version's Eclipse and ADT Plugin. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to right click -> run on the class itself and try renamining it to Test* or *Test as per the convention: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_15

Answer (score 1):

You are using JUnit 4. You must use JUnit 3 as Espresso is based on Android Instrumentation which currently only supports JUnit 3. To do this:

1. Remove the JUnit 4 reference from the project
2. Update syntax of test cases to Junit 3 i.e. remove the @Test annotations and update your test methods to be prefixed with the word "test"

Example:
Incorrect

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Example:
Correct

```
public void test()
{
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner. See instructions here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Espresso_Setup_Instructions

Also, change your test class constructor to this:

```
public TestT()
{
    super(MainActivity.class);
}
```